# React Page flickers after before it redirects based on redux value

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a login page, and what I do is I use redux to map state to props to check if the user state object exists.  If it does, it should redirect away from it to "/".  I have created a component called `PublicRoute` as shown below:

**App.js**

```
// user is loaded via this.props from redux when I map state to props.
const { user } = this.props
const isLoggedIn = _.isEmpty(user) ? false : true

<PublicRoute 
   path="/login" 
   exact
   isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
   component={Login}
/>
```

**PublicRoute.js component**

```
const PublicRoute = ({ isLoggedIn, ...props }) => {
    return isLoggedIn ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <Route {...props} />
};

export default PublicRoute
```

What happens when I am logged in and to test, I go to "/login", even though it DOES redirect to "/", the Login page still renders for a split second, even though it is in the else. I knwo this is because the redux hasnt loaded the user object for a split second, so what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use three states of the user object.

1. undefined:- initial state, where the page has started to load.
2. null:- if the user is not logged in.
3. value:- if the user is logged in.

In this way, you know the state of your user object and render appropriately.
For eg :-

```
if (user === undefined) return null;

if (user === null) return <Login />

return <Components />
```

Comment: So the three conditions should go into my PublicRoute?  and the return <Components/> Should be <Redirect/> correct?